# azure.storage.blob._shared Authentication. AzureSigningError for Azure blob

Tags: python, azure

I am working on a repository using the Azure MLOps,  I followed each and every step given in the guide to set the key vault and the production variables.

After setting everything when I  run the data_pipeline.yml file, it throws an error  like this

```
azure.storage.blob._shared.authentication.AzureSigningError: Invalid base64-encoded string: number of data characters (17) cannot be 1 more than a multiple of 4
```

when I saw the process flow, it stops at the create and register data stage and I think that error points to this stage.

so please help me to rectify the problem so that I could proceed further.

Comment: Which guide are you referring to? What are the contents of the data_pipeline.yml file?

Comment: hi, I have attached the  guide below  which I have followed till now

Comment: Can't find it yet. Could you please add the link and the file content to your question above?